# Divide by zero error when calculating return rate per customer

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9c43c0f0f8c408864c32ec976653caa2)**

```
CREATE TABLE sales (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    customerID VARCHAR,
    sales_channel VARCHAR,
    order_volume DECIMAL,
    sales_volume DECIMAL,
    return_volume DECIMAL
);

INSERT INTO sales
(customerID, sales_channel, order_volume, sales_volume, return_volume)
VALUES 
('Customer_01', 'local', '53', '0', '0'),
('Customer_01', 'website', '14', '14', '0');
```

**Expected Result:**

```
customerid    |  return_rate  |
--------------|---------------|----
Customer_01   |     0.00      |
```

---

I want to calculate the `return_rate` for the customer in the above table by dividing the `return_volume` with the `sales_volume`.

However, as you can see there is no `return_volume` for the customer therefore the result should be zero.
In Redshift I am getting error `Divide by zero`.
To solve this issue I tried to go with a `case statement` looking like this:

```
SELECT
s.customerID AS customerID,

(CASE WHEN (SUM(s.return_volume) / SUM (s.sales_volume))*-1 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 
(SUM(s.return_volume) / SUM (s.sales_volume))*-1 END ) AS return_rate

FROM sales s
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

However, I am still getting the `Divide by zero` error.
What do I need to modify the query to make it work?
(In PostgreSQL it works without any issue as you can see in the DB-Fiddle)

Answer (score 0):

Use `NULLIF()` to remove the divide by zero:

```
SELECT s.customerID,
       - SUM(s.return_volume) / NULLIF(SUM(s.sales_volume), 0) AS return_rate
FROM sales s
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```